# Apache mod_geoip module not Working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, apache2, php, nginx

I have Installed Apache mod_geoip module on Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-geoip
```

and edited file: `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/geoip.conf`
to enable:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPv6.dat
```

The, I ran the command `sudo service apache2 reload`

and also tried that options but couldn't get work

```
GeoIPUseFirstNonPrivateXForwardedForIP On
GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On
```

Its displaying wrong country, My IP address country in `CA` and its displaying `FR`

On the server, I have installed Apache and Nginx with php7.4

did I miss something to configure?

php code:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably has more to do with the GeoIP database being incomplete/out-dated than anything. As the IPv4 address space runs out of allocations, companies around the world are buying addresses from organizations in other countries. Amazon, Google, and Microsoft are doing this wherever possible as customers using their cloud services depend on the systems being accessible. ISPs are in the same boat as they pick up new customers. Your IP address may have recently belonged to a French company, and your GeoIP database is too old to know any better.

Most of the GeoIP database providers use whois records to track changes and update their database as fast as possible. Maxmind is quite transparent about the accuracy of their data, which generally hovers around 75% correct for paying customers and less for free database installations.

If you need absolute accuracy of site visitor locations, there are no fool-proof solutions. IP addresses can be reallocated anywhere in the world, spoofed, or obfuscated. GPS locations can be requested and denied, or easily falsified. The same is said about asking people for postal codes, area codes, and the like.

If the GeoIP tool is being used for stats, then it’s best to understand that some of the data will be wrong. If it’s being used to restrict access to a website/service, then it’s good to understand that some legitimate clients may be blocked. If this is being used to customize displayed content, then perhaps people should be given the option to set their location if the stuff they see is incorrect.

Hope this helps.